# Stack Exchange Sites: Saturday question cleanup?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I'm trying to track total question counts on a few Stack Exchange sites via the API and it seems that a bulk of questions are deleted on Saturdays. The chart below shows daily question count on StackOverflow. On Saturdays, the total number of questions goes down by approx. 5000 questions.

Which questions are being deleted? Is this new spam questions that accumulated over a week or is it old questions which beyond retention filter, e.g. no votes/no views/older than 5 years?

**Update 1**

Here's the query that counts total number of old and unpopular questions: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/352871/old-unloved-questions-eligible-for-auto-deletion. On Thursday it was just over 4K for StackOverflow which matches the observed drops on Saturday.

[image: Stack Overflow daily question rate]

Comment: Very true, see answer on linked dupe